# How can I debug the original C++ code in a wasm project in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webassembly

Currently I'm playing with a WebAssembly backend for a JS library. I have the project set up in VS Code, have the C++ sources there, built wasm + js wrapper files (using emscripten, where I enabled debug information and source maps) and can run all that. Unfortunately, this gives me an error in the C++ code (which works fine when compiled as a C++ application), so I want to debug the C++ code similar like you can with browsers.

I checked if there's a specific WASM extension (there's none specifically for debugging) and naively tried to set a breakpoint in the C++ code (which obviously didn't work). The launch config I have for the JS side (actually it's TypeScript) is this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch ANTLR4 test",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--no-warnings=ExperimentalWarning",
                "--loader",
                "ts-node/esm",
                "tests/test.ts",
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I can debug the TS code nicely, but not the C++ code (or its wasm equivalent).

Comment: possibly related: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/wasm-debugging-2020/

Comment: Right, I have read that posting before. However, it's for the Chrome browser, while I try to debug in Node.js and VS Code.